# JSON object not being created outside of the IDE

Tags: java, json, netbeans

I'm working with a JSON object to send an HTTP Post request. My program works perfectly fine in the IDE, but when I'm running it from the JAR file on my desktop, it's getting stuck.
The *Code*

```
        if ((act.getSource() == sendAlertButton)) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Inside send alert button handler");

            //Creating JSON
            JSONObject mainObj = new JSONObject();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Created main object");

            //Handles access token
            mainObj.put("access_token", *access token*);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Created access token");

            //Handles file format
            mainObj.put("format", "json");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Created format");

            //Handles alarm
            JSONObject alarmObj = new JSONObject();
            //Fill alarmObj
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Created alarm fields");

            //Handles event
            JSONObject eventObj = new JSONObject();
            //Fill eventObj

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Created event fields");                
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "JSON Object created successfully");

            //Send Post
            Map<String, String> headerMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            String bodyStr = mainObj.toString();
            InputStream body = new ByteArrayInputStream(bodyStr.getBytes());
            //System.out.println("Sending Post");
            post(*IP address*, headerMap, body);

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Alert sent successfully!");

        }
```

It's never outputting **"Created main object"**, so I know it's getting stuck on the `JSONObject mainObj = new JSONObject();` 
line. Any ideas why this is happening only when I run it outside of the IDE?

Comment: how are you launching outside the ide?

Comment: Depends how your build path is set up.  If your library that JSONObject depends on is made available at runtime, and lies on a path that is not accessible when you launch "outside of the IDE", then you will get an error.

Comment: After cleaning and building the project, I am running the jar file from my desktop. I'm seeing my UI and am able to do other things with my project and seem to be facing problems only with the JSON object. I'm not sure if it has something to do with the libraries or not?